# Convert a for-loop to a recursive function

Tags: python, function, recursion, iteration

Can anyone help to convert this to a recursion function?

```
def max_vel(t):
    vel = 0   
    thr = 10
    c = -0.1
    for i in range(t):
        fric = c * vel
        acc = thr + fric
        vel = vel + acc
        print fric, acc, vel
    print vel
    return vel
print max_vel(154)
```

Comment: *Why?* Iterative functions are generally better, and in python this is especially true. You avoid the recursion limit and a lot of function call overhead. By the way: in your function you are mixing computation and input/output. This is bad design. The two things should be separated to increase code re-usability.

Comment: Thanks, my aim is to grip the thought/design process for implementing recursion, so this is just a demo code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve a problem with a recursion, it is needed to state that problem in recursion manner. That means to define it in self similar way.

In this case there are variables: time, acceleration and velocity. So, main problem has to be defined with sub-problems with same variables. There are 2 (quite similar) problems we can use:

- what is acceleration and velocity after t seconds from start.
- if we have given acceleration and velocity, what will be acceleration and
  velocity after t seconds.

With that there are two (similar) recursion solutions:

```
def start_av(t):
  if t == 0: return 0, 0
  acc, vel = start_av(t-1)
  thr = 10
  c = -0.1
  fric = c*vel
  acc = thr + fric
  return (acc, vel + acc)

def given_av(t, acc=0, vel=0):
  if t == 0: return acc, vel
  thr = 10
  c = -0.1
  fric = c*vel
  acc = thr + fric
  return given_av(t-1, acc, vel + acc)    

print start_av(10)
print given_av(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

A rather simple way:

```
def max_vel(t, vel=[0], thr=10):
    c = -0.1
    if t > 0:
        fric = c * vel[0]
        acc = thr + fric
        vel[0] = vel[0] + acc
        print fric, acc, vel
        max_vel(t - 1, vel, thr)
    return vel[0]
```

Here you just decrement `t`, since this is the the number of iterations. `c` never changes, so it is not passed in the recursion. Now I use `vel` as a list of 1 element because in Python lists are mutable: this allows `vel` content to be updated by recursion calls.

Comment: your function doesn't return anything